# getting values of a torch tensor from a tensor of indices

Tags: pytorch, tensor, torch, indices

I apologize in advance for my basics knowledge of pytorch, but this problem stuck me for some time.

Suppose I have a torch tensor u of shape (8,8,1), for example

```
u = tensor([[0.0000, 0.1429, 0.2857, 0.4286, 0.5714, 0.7143, 0.8571, 1.0000],
[0.0000, 0.1429, 0.2886, 0.4470, 0.5896, 0.7171, 0.8571, 1.0000],
[0.0000, 0.1446, 0.3182, 0.4934, 0.6302, 0.7424, 0.8588, 1.0000],
[0.0000, 0.1470, 0.3154, 0.4734, 0.5974, 0.7258, 0.8603, 1.0000],
[0.0000, 0.1397, 0.2742, 0.4026, 0.5266, 0.6846, 0.8530, 1.0000],
[0.0000, 0.1412, 0.2576, 0.3698, 0.5066, 0.6818, 0.8554, 1.0000],
[0.0000, 0.1429, 0.2829, 0.4104, 0.5530, 0.7114, 0.8571, 1.0000],
[0.0000, 0.1429, 0.2857, 0.4286, 0.5714, 0.7143, 0.8571, 1.0000]])
```

and a tensor of size (2,8,8) of indices of u that I'm interested in

```
indices = tensor(
[[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2],
[0, 3, 0, 4, 0, 5, 0, 5],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2],
[0, 3, 0, 4, 0, 5, 0, 5],
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2],
[1, 3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 1, 5],
[2, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2],
[2, 3, 2, 4, 2, 5, 2, 5]],    

[[3, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 1],
 [3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 3, 5],
 [4, 0, 3, 0, 3, 0, 3, 1],
 [4, 2, 4, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5],
 [5, 0, 5, 0, 4, 0, 4, 1],
 [5, 2, 5, 3, 5, 5, 5, 5],
 [5, 0, 5, 0, 5, 1, 5, 2],
 [5, 3, 5, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5]]])
```

I would like to have a torch tensor result of the same size of u, but where `result[i][j] = u[indices[0][i][j],indices[1][i][j]` (example: `result[0][0] = u[0][3], result[0][1] = u[3][0], result[4][5] = u[5][0]`...)

I tried to use torch.gather but I couldn't manage to make it work at all, I tried changing the .view of the tensors but I couldn't match the dimensions. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Start by repeating u tensor like the size of indices [(8, 8) -> (2,8,8)]. After You can use the gather.

```
repeated_u = u.unsqueeze(dim=0).repeat(indices.shape[0],1,1)
result = torch.gather(repeated_u, 2, indices)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the thing is that doing this I get is a tensor of dimension (2,8,8) where the two first elements are computed taking in consideration the respective first and second element of indices (so `repeated_u[0]` is computed by `indices[0]` and `repeated_u[1]` by `indices[1]`. What I needed maybe can be understood by viewing `u` as a matrix of elements `u[i][j]`. From this I need to compute a tensor of the same dimension where each element has the respective value of `indices[0]` as row index and `indices[1]` as column index. Sorry for not being clear, I hope this is

Answer (score 0):

For presented shapes (`u.shape -- (8, 8)`, `indices.shape -- (2, 8, 8)`) seems like naive indexing works fine `result = u[indices[0], indices[1]]`

Comment: Oh my god thanks I can't believe it was this easy.... I just got stack on gather, thanks a lot